# Where can I find the proofs of the properties of exponentiation when powers are members of ℕ, ℤ, ℚ, ℙ, and ℝ?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, exponential-function, exponentiation

> Where can I find the proofs of the properties of exponentiation when powers are members of ℕ, ℤ, ℚ, ℙ, and ℝ?

[image]

So far, I have only found this:

http://andrusia.com/math/preliminaries/ExponentiationTheorems.pdf

But I think this only works for exponents that are members of ℕ, and I don't even know if what is offered in that document is an explanation more than a proof, since they should be proven using induction and not ellipsis "..." . Do you consider these are correct proofs?

On the other hand I haven't been able to find over the internet the proofs for exponents members of ℤ, ℚ, ℙ, and ℝ (where ℙ = ℝ\ℚ, to clarify what ℙ is).

Do you know where can these proofs be found?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so $\mathbb P$ is the irrational numbers?

Comment: Yes; I always have problems giving irrational numbers a sign that anybody can understand.

Comment: Yes, it is odd that there is no standard notation for them. You can say $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q.$ Actually, here you don't really need to mention them... the function for $x,y\in\mathbb R$ will agree with the function for $x,y\in\mathbb Q$ on $\mathbb Q$... so asking about $\mathbb R$ is really just asking about how to extend to the irrationals.

Comment: Before you can prove it for non-naturals you must *define* it for non-naturals.  Usually these are easily proven by applying the definition.  Example if $a =\frac pq\in \mathbb Q$ then $x^{a}= (\sqrt[q]{x})^p$ and the proofs follow.

Comment: The negative reals and the non-negative rules behave differently under exponent.

Comment: Note that the irrational numbers are not closed under either operation ($\pi-\pi=0$, $\sqrt{2}sqrt{2}=2$), hence they don't have an algebraic structure. However, these power laws are usually proved for (at least) monoids.

Comment: The Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation contains an outline of how exponentiation is extended from exponents in $\mathbb{N}$ to integer, rational, real and complex exponents.